# Why am I receiving null as a response for an sql column with data in it? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, sql, authentication, mysqli

I am building a log in system and every other part works perfectly fine except for the portion that cross references the entered password with the password in the database. So when I checked to see if the passwords match I realized that the password from the database is coming back as null. May I ask what is happening?? (There is no issue with the "uidExists" method, it seems to just be in the "loginUser" method).

This is based of of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCo6JqGMi30

I believe its around the hour and 40 minute mark he gets to the loginUser function.

```
function loginUser($conn,$username,$pwd){
$uidExists = uidExists($conn,$username,$username);

if($uidExists === false){
    header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongslogin");
    exit();
}
else{
    echo $pwd;
    if(is_null($uidExists["userPwd"])){
        echo "Empty bruv";
    }
    else{
        echo $uidExists["userPwd"];
    }
}


function uidExists($conn,$username,$email){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userUid = ? OR userEmail = ?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
    exit();
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$username,$email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){
    return $row;
}
else{
    $result = false;
    return $result;
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

}

Comment: At index 1:39:02 it shows an insert statement which shows the column names as: `usersName,usersEmail,usersId,usersPwd` - note the `users` where your query has `userEmail` or `userUid` - so either you deviated from the lesson or your select statement and/or your result reference is incorrect.  I'd suggest posting your `CREATE` sql statement to confirm.  Also note your `mysqli_stmt_close()` statement is unreachable.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't look right:

```
$uidExists = uidExists($conn,$username,$username);
```

Should this be:

```
$uidExists = uidExists($conn,$username,$userPwd);
```

Comment: Its how its made in the video and It works perfectly fine on his end.

Comment: @RobMoll are you sure it should be sending the password though, as per your suggestion? The uidExists function expects an email as the 3rd parameters, not a password

Comment: I just went through the video and @ 1:39:00 he shows that he does this because the user can provide a username or email. So this does not appear to be an issue. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RobMoll Yeah at first I thought you were on to something but then I reviewed the video and remembered he did that as to accept email and username as inputs